# AngularJS - Submitting PHP Form Using ng-controller

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm really fresh in AngularJS and PHP. I'm trying to develop Contact Form Using AngularJs and PHP. It is a simple contact form where a user enters the First Name, Last Name, Email, and Message. 
I already included in HTML - AngularJS Validation Classes, so validation is the client side (for now), that's fine with me. 
I know that is possible to code validation with PHP for server side.
You will tell me what is better. 
Problem is how to code PHP that will send user data and user message to my personal email or any receiver email that is in PHP file. 
And I want to include the same form as part of AngularJs Template for ng-rout.
And I if you can code the same form only with AngularJS not using PHP that's fine with me, I just want to find one version of a solution that is working for real-life usage.

So, can anyone of you guys send me a solution code for my problem? Here is my code so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
                <title>Contact Form - AngularJS</title>
                    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
                            integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
                                <!-- Custom CSS -->
                                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mainStyle.css">
                                            <!-- Angular JS form RootFolder + uiRouter CDN  -->
                                                <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
                                                   <script src="js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
                                                        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

  </head>
<body ng-app="app">
<div class="container-fluid ">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-12 contentSection d-none d-md-block d-md-none"><!-- Content Section -->
            <!-- Contact Form  -->
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-6 text-left">
                <!-- FORM -->
                <form ng-controller="formcontroller" name="contactForm" novalidate>
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Your First Name" name="firstName" ng-model="contact.firstName" ng-required="true" class="first_name"/>
                        <div ng-show="contactForm.firstName.$touched && contactForm.firstName.$invalid" class="row justify-content-center mt-2">
                        <div class="col text-left">
                        <small class="errorForm">Enter Your First Name</small>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Last Name" name="lastName" ng-model="contact.lastName" ng-required="true" class="last_name"/>
                        <div ng-show="contactForm.lastName.$touched && contactForm.lastName.$invalid" class="row justify-content-center mt-2">
                        <div class="col text-left">
                        <small class="errorForm">Enter Your Last Name</small>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row justify-content-start mt-2">
                        <div class="col-8">
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Your Email" name="emailSender" ng-model="contact.emailSender" ng-required="true" class="contact_email" />
                        <div ng-show="contactForm.emailSender.$touched && contactForm.emailSender.$invalid" class="row justify-content-center mt-2">
                        <div class="col text-left">
                        <small class="errorForm">Enter Your Valid Email</small>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row justify-content-start">
                        <div class="col-8">
                        <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" ng-model="contact.message" ng-required="true" rows="5" class="cMessage"></textarea>
                        <div ng-show="contactForm.message.$touched && contactForm.message.$invalid" class="row justify-content-center mt-2">
                        <div class="col text-left">
                        <small class="errorForm">Enter Your Message</small>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row justify-content-start mt-4 mb-3">
                        <div class="col-10">
                        <button class="send" type="submit" ng-disabled="contactForm.$invalid">Send</button>
                        <div ng-show="successMessage" class="row justify-content-center mt-2">
                        <div class="col text-left">
                        <small class="succesForm" >Will be in touch with you soon!</small>
                        </div>
                        </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form> 
                <!-- FORM -->
                </div>
            </div>
            </div><!-- End of Content Section -->
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>

<!-- ==================================================================================================== -->

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<script src="js/angularScript.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Aangular JS - my angular code so far...

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate']);



app.controller("formcontroller", function($scope, $http){

   });
```

CSS

```
/*--- CONTACT ---*/
.first_name,
.last_name,
.contact_email,
.cMessage {
  width: 80%;
  outline: none ;
  border: none;
  border-radius: none;
  padding: 2vh 0 1vh 1%;
  border-bottom: 0.1vh solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #3b634f;
  transition: 0.8s ease;
}
.first_name:hover, .last_name:hover, .contact_email:hover, .cMessage:hover {
  border-bottom: 0.1vh solid rgb(83, 143, 255);
}
/*-- Validation Classe --*/
.first_name.ng-invalid.ng-touched,
.last_name.ng-invalid.ng-touched,
.contact_email.ng-invalid.ng-touched,
.cMessage.ng-invalid.ng-touched
 {border-bottom: 0.2vh solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);}
 .errorForm {
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.418);
}
.succesForm {
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.61);
}
.send {
  padding: 1vh 6% 1vh 6%;
  background-color: #538a6f;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.send[disabled="disabled"] {
  opacity: 0.4;
  cursor: not-allowed !important; 
}
/*--- Contact SM ---*/
.contactInfoSm  p {
  font-size: 2.5vmin;
}
.first_nameSm,
.last_nameSm,
.contact_emailSm,
.cMessageSm {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none ;
  padding: 0.5vh 0 0.5vh 0;
  border: 0.1vh solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #3b634f;
  text-indent: 10px;
  transition: 0.8s ease;
}
.first_nameSm:hover, .last_nameSm:hover, .contact_emailSm:hover, .cMessageSm:hover {
  border-bottom: 0.1vh solid rgb(83, 143, 255);
}
.errorFormSm {
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.618);
  font-size: 2vmin;
}
.succesForm-Sm {
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.61);
}
```

PHP - ??? :)

Please help me with these guys I really want to learn. 
Thank you! ;)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ng-submit` in your form to trigger a `$scope` method, then send a post request to a PHP page for instance
Take a look at this example : http://www.chaosm.net/blog/2014/05/21/angularjs-contact-form-with-bootstrap-and-phpmailer/

Comment: OK! This is looking promising I will check this for sure. Thank you ;)